# Jquery: How to add spinner to input type button

Tags: jquery

see this [URL](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Built-In-Loading-Indicator-In-Buttons-Button-Loader/) for the jquery plugin of the loading indicator

### see the code

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.buttonLoader = function (action) {
        var self = $(this);

        //start loading animation
        if (action == 'start') {
            if ($(self).attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            //disable buttons when loading state
            $('.has-spinner').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $(self).attr('data-btn-text', $(self).text());
            //binding spinner element to button and changing button text
            $(self).html('<span class="spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>Loading');
            $(self).addClass('active');
        }
        //stop loading animation
        if (action == 'stop') {
            $(self).html($(self).attr('data-btn-text'));
            $(self).removeClass('active');
            //enable buttons after finish loading
            $('.has-spinner').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

the above code work fine with html button tag `<button class="btn btn-default has-spinner" id="btnTest" runat="server">Test IT</button>`

### call the code like this way

```
var btn = $("#btnTest");
$(btn).buttonLoader('start');
```

and stop like `$(btn).buttonLoader('stop');`

but the problem is if i am using html submit button then whole code does not work. So what change i need to add as a result it should work for **html button and submit button too**.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that submit button will make the code not working. Can you show how it is not working?

Comment: please add the fiddle

Comment: Did you try `<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>` ?

Comment: how to make the animation work for submit button with input type tag......share idea

Answer (score 4):

As @Monojit and @you.know.nothing mentioned, you need to use the button tag with attribute submit. I don't think you can do the same thing for a tag of type input though.

If you check what the code does, it simply adds markup to the inner html of an a and button tags.

Either way, I'm providing a working example. The button is of type submit and the id is the one you choose: btnTest.

Note: For you to trigger the spinning animation, you have to bind the click event.

```js
$('#btnTest').click(function() {
  var btn = $(this);
  $(btn).buttonLoader('start');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(btn).buttonLoader('stop');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.spinner {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s, width 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s, width 0.25s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s, width 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s, width 0.25s;
}

.has-spinner.active {
  cursor: progress;
}

.has-spinner.active .spinner {
  opacity: 1;
  width: auto;
}

.has-spinner.btn.active .spinner {
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:150px">
  <button class="btn btn-default has-spinner" id="btnTest">Trigger Spinner</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script>


  (function($) {
    $.fn.buttonLoader = function(action) {
      var self = $(this);
      //start loading animation
      if (action == 'start') {
        if ($(self).attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        //disable buttons when loading state
        $('.has-spinner').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(self).attr('data-btn-text', $(self).text());
        //binding spinner element to button and changing button text
        $(self).html('<span class="spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>Loading');
        $(self).addClass('active');
      }
      //stop loading animation
      if (action == 'stop') {
        $(self).html($(self).attr('data-btn-text'));
        $(self).removeClass('active');
        //enable buttons after finish loading
        $('.has-spinner').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    }
  })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I was not reading your question carefully.

For form submit button, simply set type of your button to "submit", as in:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn_submit">Test Button</button>
```

You cannot add html content to your `<input type="button|submit" />` elements as this element type cannot have nested elements, so instead of using `<input type="submit" />`, use `<button type="submit">Button label</button>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i test your code but no spinner gets attached to sumbit button. sorry it is not working.